# Prevent inserting repeating values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am still trying to insert values into a ratings table, I have tried 2 different approaches and both do the same thing my first approach is as follows:

```
DECLARE
rate NUMBER;
lv_cat NUMBER;
rate_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..1
LOOP
INSERT INTO RATINGS (HOTELID, CATEGORYID, RATING)
SELECT a.IDHOTEL, b.CATEGORYID, INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words)
FROM review a, SeedWords b
WHERE a.IDHOTEL = i;
END LOOP;
END;
```

My second approach is:

```
DECLARE
  i         NUMBER := 1;
  lv_hotel  NUMBER := 1;
  lv_rate   NUMBER;
  LV_RATE_NUM NUMBER;
  lv_cat NUMBER;
  hotel_match NUMBER;
  cat_match NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_hotel IN (SELECT a.IDHotel AS lv_hotel,INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words) AS LV_RATE_NUM, b.CATEGORYID AS lv_cat
                      FROM review a, SEEDWORDS b)
  LOOP
     --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('start');
     IF rec_hotel.LV_RATE_NUM > 0 THEN
       lv_rate := rec_hotel.LV_RATE_NUM*.006;
        ELSIF rec_hotel.LV_RATE_NUM < 1 THEN
        lv_rate := rec_hotel.LV_RATE_NUM*10;
     ELSIF rec_hotel.LV_RATE_NUM = 0 THEN
       lv_rate := 8.6/3;
     END IF;
   INSERT INTO RATINGS
    VALUES (rec_hotel.lv_hotel, rec_hotel.lv_cat, lv_rate);
     --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(LV_RATE_NUM);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This is suppose to find  words in the reviews. There are 4 categories that the words fall into so there are only supposed to be 4 ratings per hotel, but instead I am getting hundreds of ratings per hotel. What can I add into either block of code to make sure that for each hotelID there are only 4 records, one record for the rating of each categoryID?

My expected out put would look something like this with the rating value being the number of words found all the reviews for the the hotel:

```
HOTELID | CATEGORYID | RATING
   1    |        1   |    5
   1    |        2   |    10
   1    |        3   |    2
   1    |        4   |    6
   2    |        1   |    6
   2    |        2   |    10 
   2    |        3   |    4
   2    |        4   |    2
```

My review table is the following:

```
Hotel Id | Review |
  1      |  "LARGE STRING"
  1      |  "LARGE STRING"
  1      |  "LARGE STRING"
  1      |  "LARGE STRING"
  1      |  "LARGE STRING"
  1      |  "LARGE STRING"
  2      |  "LARGE STRING"
  2      |  "LARGE STRING"
  2      |  "LARGE STRING"
  2      |  "LARGE STRING"
```

And My SeedWord Table is set up as follows

```
SEED ID| SEED_WORD|CATEGORYID
  1    |  "WORD"  |      1
  2    |  "WORD"  |      1
  3    |  "WORD"  |      2
  4    |  "WORD"  |      2
  5    |  "WORD"  |      3
  6    |  "WORD"  |      3
  7    |  "WORD"  |      4
  8    |  "WORD"  |      4
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It seems that your review table has many rows against each hotel. Can you please let us know how you want to average the rating. Let's say for word1 if there are 50 rows with different ratings then how to aggregate those ratings? It would be appreciated if you can share sample data and expected output along with the table structure.

Comment: "*There are 4 categories that the words fall into so there are only supposed to be 4 ratings per hotel,*" But your seed table shows multiple rows per CATEGORYID. So for each HOTEL_ID you will get a product of `rows in REVIEW multiplied by rows in SEEDWORD`.

Comment: There are a total of 15 seed words per category (only 4 categories) they are discriptive words that people use for a "good rating" so the more of the words are found in the review the better the rating is for that category. I would like the Rating column in the ratings table to have the total amount of seed words found with in all of the reviews for that hotel for that category.